# Inline javascript function not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript, inline

scenario is -

```
bnm () function is to be called for first time and resultObject constructed .

Later on , item function is to be called dynamically .

This function get called successfully  in IE 7 .

but not in IE 8 ,  9 ,  10 .

Please suggest any solution  .
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
   function bnm(xmlData)
   {     
       this.item = function (recordno, itemname)
       {
         // some code
          return result;
       }

       return this;
   }
```

// Here i am calling above function

```
       resultObject = bnm(anyData);

       text1.value = resultObject.item(8, 'Policy1');
       text2.value = resultObject.item(6, 'Policy4');
       text3.value = resultObject.item(2, 'Policy8');
```

Comment: I think the function itself is working, but referring HTML element in the way you (probably) do, is deprecated for over a decade ago. Please set `id`s for elements and use `document.getElementById()` to get a reference.

Comment: How to call item function in IE10 ?

Comment: To answer this we need more information, basicly your code should work. Please add the relevant _real_ code to your question, and the HTML snippet too. You could also provide a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) snippet to show a non-working example. Have you tested other browsers than IEs? Any errors in the console?

Comment: i can not do it due to security policies . The html  is not imp here . Can you suggest alternate way of calling inliine functions and anonymous functions .

Comment: Hmm... I mean it would be nice to see the construction of the script and HTML. You can still narrow them down or use partial pseudo code. Or if it's something within `// some code`... Definitely inline functions, constructors and anonymous functions are working in all IEs. Btw. what exactly means "not working", do you get wrong results, not results at all, or an error?

Comment: What do you think `this` is in your `bnm` function?